# ¿Como ejecutar función de postgresql en php con pdo?

Tags: php, postgresql, web, pdo

Me gustaria saber como puedo llamar una funcion o procedimiento almacenado en postgresql mediante PHP con PDO.
Supongamos que tengo la funcion en postgresql:

```
buscarporcategoria(categoria character varying);
```

Y su contenido es el siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.buscarporcategoria(
    _categoria_ character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(isbn character varying, titulo character varying, edicion integer, paginas integer, fecha date, nombre character varying, apellido character varying, categoria character varying, editorial character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
    AS $BODY$


BEGIN
    FOR nombre, apellido, isbn, titulo, edicion, paginas, fecha, categoria, editorial IN
        SELECT 
            autores.nombre, autores.apellido,
            libros.isbn, libros.titulo, 
            libros.edicion, libros.paginas, libros.fecha_publicacion,
            categorias.categoria,         
            editoriales.editorial
            FROM autores
            INNER JOIN libros_por_autor ON autores.id = libros_por_autor.id_autores
            INNER JOIN libros ON libros.id = libros_por_autor.id_libros
            INNER JOIN libros_por_categoria ON libros_por_categoria.id_libros = libros.id
            INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = libros_por_categoria.id_categorias
            INNER JOIN libros_por_editorial ON libros_por_editorial.id_libros = libros.id
            INNER JOIN editoriales ON editoriales.id = libros_por_editorial.id_editoriales        
            WHERE categorias.categoria ILIKE '%'||_categoria_||'%'
        LOOP
            RETURN NEXT;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
```

La consulta dentro del gestor funciona correctamente y devuelve lo que necesito, pero la estoy tratando de ejecutar así desde PHP con PDO y creo que no esta bien hacerlo así pues parece que se ejecuta correctamente, pero la verdad no devuelve nada:

```
$query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM buscarporcategoria(?)');
$query->bindParam(1, $this->autor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$this->con->close();
return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Me gustaria saber como seria la forma correcta de ejecutar funciones de postgresql y obtener los resultados como si la ejecutara desde el mismo gestor.

A proposito, asi es como imprimo los resultados de la consulta:

```
foreach( $libros as $libro ){
                    echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$libro->isbn.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->titulo.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->edicion.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->paginas.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->fecha.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->nombre.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->apellido.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->categoria.'</td>
                        <td>'.$libro->editorial.'</td>
                    </tr>';

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sería lo que se tiene que cambiar para llamar una función usando PDO.

```
$query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM buscarporcategoria(?)');
$query->bindParam(1, $this->autor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

por:

```
$query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT buscarporcategoria(?)');
//Aqui se realiza un cambio de bindParam a bindValue puesto que tu función no usa ningún 
//parametro de entrada o salida sino más bien un valor que sería "categoria"
$query->bindValue(1, $this->autor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Debo señalar que: la prueba que hice fue con un procedimiento bastante menos pesado que el tuyo por lo que hacer uso de un:

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print "RESULTADO DE LA FUNCION";
print_r($result) ;
```

Antes de enviarlo a imprimir podría ayudarte para saber si efectivamente se esta ejecutando tu función o no.

Espero te ayude saludos.

Comment: No amigo, no me funciona aun, gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Comment: Antes que nada debo disculparme puesto que he confundido procedimiento y función; ante esto he realizado una pequeña replica de lo que sería la llamada a una función de select en mi servidor local. Ahora actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono perfectamente!.