# Consulta basica de PDO

Tags: php, pdo

estoy empezando con `PDO` y tengo un problema estoy siguiendo un curso el cual estoy copiando todo al pie de la letra pero no me devuelve datos 
al hacer un `print_r`
me devuelve un 1 , y en la base de datos tengo 3 usuarios ya ingresados con `nombre , email y ID`

y la verdad ya no se cual podría ser el problema , lo he visto una y otra vez el vídeo , he probado otras formas pero el resultado me lleva al mismo.

De antemano muchas gracias

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname = prueba', 'root', '');
$result = $conexion ->query('SELECT * FROM usuarios');

foreach ($result as $res)
{
    echo $res["nombre"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Prueba así: `$sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios"; foreach ($conexion ->query($sql) as $res) { echo $res["nombre"].PHP_EOL;}` [Revisa el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php)  o bien usa uno de los métodos `fetch` Se da por supuesto que tu tabla `usuarios`  tiene una columna `nombre`

Answer (score 2):

Te comento que tu código debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');
$result = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
$ejecutaResult = $conexion->prepare($result);
$ejecutaResult->execute();

        foreach ($ejecutaResult as $res) {
            echo $res["nombre"].PHP_EOL;
        }
```

**Donde como notas los cambios son:**

> 1. La consulta la dejo en una variable sola
> 2. declaro una nueva variable que va a ser igual al objeto de conexión y con esa misma accedo al método prepare() y paso como
>      argumento la variable que contiene mi SELECT
> 3. La variable anterior es la misma que va a acceder al método execute, para ejecutar la consulta
> 4. También si no estas pasando valores dinámicos a tu consulta es decir variables que modifiquen el resultado, prueba usar comillas
>      simples en vez de dobles

La última variable usada es la que trataré en el foreach y lo colocaré un nuevo alias para recorrer las columnas que me esta trayendo

Answer (score 2):

Prueba ejecutando esto:

```
<?php
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';
try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios');
$sentencia->execute();

//Esta salida se acerca más al resultado que buscas
while ($result = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $result['nombre']."</br>";
    }
?>
```

Es un script de una pregunta que respondí hace algún tiempo, lo adapté un poco para tu caso, supongo que sería más o menos lo que buscas. Si deseas ver la respuesta total esta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131109/como-ejecutar-funci%C3%B3n-de-postgresql-en-php-con-pdo/131118#131118).

Pdta: Personalmente pienso que si vas a usar PDO, es bastante recomendable que explotes las funciones FETCH.

Answer (score 2):

muchas gracias a todos por responder , ya encontre cual era mi problema y es que en la base de datos estaba haciendo un espacio lo estaba dejando asi

mysql:host=localhost;dbname = prueba

y es sin espacios , tiene que ser asi

mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba

gracias por las respuestas rapidas